# Nested function does not have same signature as delegate

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to achieve a currying-like effect in VB. I want to be able to do this:

```
Dim wrap = WrapNumber("-")
wrap(5) 'returns "-5-"
```

Here's my function:

```
Private Function WrapNumber(ByVal separator As String) As Func(Of Integer, String)

    Return Function(ByRef number As Integer) As String
               Return separator + number + separator
           End Function

End Function
```

I get an error on the `Return` line with this message:

> Nested function does not have the same signature as delegate `Func(Of Integer, String)`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. The function `WrapNumber` returns a function which takes an `Integer` and returns a `String`, so from what I can see it has the same type as the `Func` given in the `WrapNumber` signature.

Comment: Just spitballing, but I bet the `ByRef` is causing your problems. `Func` has no support for ByRef arguments.

Comment: Remove the `ByRef` and use `&` not `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn Option Strict On, it will show you a lot of what's going wrong. In addition to ByRef not being required as stated in the comments, the concatenation is trying to treat separator as a double. If you make those changes then it works fine:

```
Dim wrap = WrapNumber("-")
Dim test As String = wrap(5)
'test is equal to "-5-"

Private Function WrapNumber(ByVal separator As String) As Func(Of Integer, String)
    Return Function(number As Integer) As String
               Return separator & number.ToString & separator
           End Function
End Function
```

Comment: You can drop the outer `ByVal` too (at least for consistency). Same for the `ToString` it isn't strictly needed